# Is it possible to set 2 variables with one set in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Good morning Stack overflow.

At the top of one of my stored procedures I have 2 variables for my dates I use.
**@StartDate** is for the start of the current day and **@EndDate** is for the current time of the day.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

PRINT @StartDate
PRINT @EndDate
```

I was wondering if it is possible to set both **@StartDate** and **@EndDate** to **GETDATE()** in the same line?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try? If so, what happened?

Comment: I was trying things like "SET StartDate, EndDate = GETDATE()" but that didn't work. I was just looking for a way to do it rather than calling GETDATE() twice or assigning one variable into another.
Its not really an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll put you out of your misery: No, you can't. My guess here is that either you want both variables to be exactly the same (eliminating any possibility of two calls to `GETDATE()` returning different values, however small), or you just want fewer function calls. SQL Server doesn't support syntax like

```
SET @StartDate = @EndDate = GETDATE()
```

That's even leaving aside the implicit narrowing from `DATETIME` to `DATE` (althoguh that's not really an issue). Best you can do is

```
SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
SET @EndDate = @StartDate
```

Unless you just want to save a line in which case you can comma separate the `@Variable = GETDATE()` calls and only use one `SELECT`.

## EDIT

Forgot to add this example - could reduce to one line thus:

```
SELECT @EndDate = GETDATE(), @StartDate = @EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. If I was to put one variable into another I would have to put EndDate into StartDate as StartDate does not need the time part of the DATETIME. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

SET can only assign one variable at a time, but SELECT multiple.

so that's what you want:

```
SELECT @StartDate = GETDATE(), @EndDate = GETDATE()
```